# SQL server version upgrade

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to upgrade Microsoft SQL server version from 12.0 to 15.0 in Azure. Can anyone help with this issue?

[image: Current version of SQL server]

Comment: You tagged both `sql-server` (which assumes a VM?) and `azure-sql-database` (presumably Azure's SQL Server-as-a-service). Which one are you using? Just note that the maintenance of SQL DB (the service) isn't something you need to worry about). Also, regarding SQL Server upgrades, that type of question probably fits best on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can't upgrade the Version of Azure SQL Database, Microsoft controls that. 12.0.2000.8 *is* the latest Azure SQL Database version. You can see it was updated not even a month ago. Note that Azure SQL Database and SQL Server use different versioning numbers. A version 15 of Azure SQL Database is likely years away.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the version but you can set the compatibility version of DB which is more important and where you should focus on.

Based on MS doc below, yes, it says Azure SQL DB always run on latest stable version.
You may update DB compatibility version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview

http://davebland.com/azure-sql-db-and-version